# Variable parameters list in WSDL

Tags: wsdl

I need to implement a WSDL interface (HTTP binding) for a variable list function. What I need to do is something very similar to a wrapper for an ipothetic WSDL export of a printf function, in example. The parameters that i'll receive will have both a name and a value, and they are both not known in advance. So an input message could be like:

param1=value1
param2=value2
param3=value3
....
paramN=valueN

etc, and the name ("paramX"), the value ("valueX") and total number of parameters are not known.
What is the best way to model this kind of function with WSDL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an array of objects, each consisting of a name and a value.

Comment: Thank you! It was that simple :)

Comment: It's easy to be distracted into modelling everything at the level of the API in a web service, when often pushing down one level is much simpler.